# Error al expandir filas, después de destruir y recargar los dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hola estoy trabajando con dataTables para gestionar mis datos que traigo desde mi contralador en codeigniter todo eso va bien,y también he programado otras funciones para filtrar mi información, que las llamo usando unos radiobutton, todo esto funciona muy bien, el problema esta en el dataTables cuando necesito expadir cada fila ya que este es responsive, el problema me salta al destruir el datatables y crear uno de nuevo esto me sale en la consola: Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined. alguna idea del problema?

esta es una parte del html

```html
<button id="MostrarTodo">mostrar</button>
<input type="radio" name="estado" value="1" onclick="filtroEstado((this.value));">
<input type="radio" name="estado" value="2" onclick="filtroEstado((this.value));">
<input type="radio" name="estado" value="3" onclick="filtroEstado((this.value));">

<table class="table" id="datatable" width="100%">
  <thead>
<tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Ubicación</th>
 <th>Estado</th>
 <th>Ciudad</th>
 <th>Tipo</th>
 <th>Opciones</th>
</tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody id="resultados"></tbody>
 </table>
```

y mi script

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    table = $("#datatable").DataTable({
        'ajax': baseurl+'spaces/getSpaces',
        'orders': [],
        responsive: true
    }); 
});

$('#MostrarTodo').on( 'click', function () {
    table.destroy();
    table = $("#datatable").DataTable({
        'ajax': baseurl+'spaces/getSpaces',
        'orders': [],
        responsive: true
    }); 
    $('input[name=estado]').attr('checked',false);
});

function filtroEstado(id){
  table.destroy();
  table = $("#datatable").DataTable({
    'ajax': baseurl+'spaces/filterState/'+id,
    'orders': [],
    responsive: true
  }); 

}
```

este es el mensaje de error completo

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined
    at u. (jquery.dataTables.min.js:120)
    at Function.isShown (jquery.dataTables.min.js:102)
    at HTMLTableCellElement. (dataTables.responsive.js:469)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)

y estos sons las librerias JS que utilizo:

```html
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/vendors/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/vendors/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/vendors/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el mensaje completo? También muéstranos las librerías que estás importando (e.g. `<link href="...">`)

Comment: gracias por responder, ahora agrego el mensaje completo y también las librerías que estoy utilizando.